# App is crash when i tap on uiimageview in uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, xcode8

I am new in iOS development, use xcode 8.2.1 & swift 3. I take uitableview in view controller, in uitableviewcell I take uiimageview when i tap on it app is crash and same issue is occur when I take button and perform button action .

The error is:

> sampleToRunBuild[3752:1620857] -[sampleToRunBuild.TapViewController
>   TappedOnImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x141e07bc0
>   2017-04-13 18:18:00.531126 sampleToRunBuild[3752:1620857] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[sampleToRunBuild.TapViewController TappedOnImage:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x141e07bc0'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x18343d1b8 0x181e7455c 0x183444268 0x183441270 0x18333a80c 0x1898b3f80 0x1898b7688 0x18947e73c
>   0x18931d0f0 0x1898a7680 0x1898a71e0 0x1898a649c 0x18931b30c
>   0x1892ebda0 0x189ad575c 0x189acf130 0x1833eab5c 0x1833ea4a4
>   0x1833e80a4 0x1833162b8 0x184dca198 0x1893567fc 0x189351534
>   0x100065f30 0x1822f95b8) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught
>   exception of type NSException

my code is :

```
import UIKit

class TapViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mycell")

        let img: UIImageView = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
        let img2: UIImageView = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView

        img.tag = indexPath.row
        img2.tag = indexPath.row

        img.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        img2.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let tapped:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("TappedOnImage:")))
        tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tapped.delegate = self
        img.addGestureRecognizer(tapped)


        let tapped1:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("TappedOnImage:")))
        tapped1.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tapped1.delegate = self
        img.addGestureRecognizer(tapped1)

        return cell!
    }

    func TappedOnImage(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
        print("tap on imageview")
    }
}
```

[image: This is storyboard screenshot]

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

add `UITapGestureRecognizer` like below code

```
   let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)


func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    let tappedImage = tapGestureRecognizer.view as! UIImageView

    // Your action
}
```

Comment: your welcome please respond on my answer @KunalMalve

Answer (score 0):

you need to use

```
#selector(TapViewController.imageTapped(sender:))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using swift 3, don't use `Selector()` anymore, use the `#selector` syntax instead.

e.g.

```
let tapped1:UITapGestureRecognizer = 
    UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(TappedOnImage))
```

The reason why your code did not work is that you forgot to add the argument label `sender` to selector string. That's one of the disadvantages of using the old syntax - it does not tell you the mistake at compile time. With the new syntax, there will be a compiler error if you wrote the selector incorrectly, and you don't even need to care about argument labels, you just need the name.